# How to reverse-engineer formula being used given certain amount of value pairs?

Tags: regression, curve-fitting, interpolation

I have these value pairs:

```
    x     y
  ----   ---
  2400   588
  3500   435
  5000   300
 20000    87
 35000    46
 50000    30
 70000    16
 95000     8
110000     5
```

(I have the means of getting more data points if necessary. That is, I can punch any x in my system and I get the resulting y returned)

So the system is definitely using a formula to give me an y for each x I punch. Is there a way to figure it out?

I'm not that good with mathematics... I have tried in some online calculators and it seems to be some sort of logarithmic function, so when trying logarithmic regression I get something similar but with quite some amount of error. Not sure if it is because the number of data pairs I'm giving are too little or because there is a better approach than logarithmic regression.

Comment: Is it deterministic? (do you always get the same output for the same input). [Gaussian process emulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process_emulator) are often used in practice for this sort of problem, rather than the shrewd guesses as to the kind of function someone might have chosen to program that "reverse-engineering" of the function implies.

Comment: yes, it is deterministic. For any given x the same y is always returned. The reason why I want to "reverse-engineer" the formula is because currently to get an y from an x I need to access an external service(somebody's website). I want to "own" the formula so I can use it at my own will in my sql database for my own operations whenever I want and without any limit on amount of requests. I don't understand how these Gaussian process emulators can help me here. Care to give a practical example or ellaborate? Thanks!

Comment: Basically they interpolate - which is what you'll have to do if you (or someone here) can't guess the function. I said they're often used in practice because in practice you can usually check the code or ask someone what the function is, but when the function's very computationally intensive you may not have the time/resources to evaluate $y$ for all the $x$s you'd like. Note that for guessing, some idea of the context might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately your replies don't help me... maybe you are asuming I have more knowledge in mathematics and statistics than what I really have. I didn't understand what you meant by Gaussian Process Emulators... I didn't understand what you mean by "they interpolate"... Plus if I would be able to check the code and see what the function is I would not be asking the question here :-)

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation. I really just wanted to point out an alternative to guessing the function - which could be very easy or very hard (there are an infinite no. ways of mapping $x$s to $y$s). You could make it easier by describing the context, as I said, & by describing what you know of constraints on suitable functions. Are $x$ or $y$ bounded? Are there asymptotes? Must the function be monotonic?  Why are $x$ & $y$ all integers? - is $y$ being rounded?